# Ubuntu Studio only shows 1 window at a time

Tags: dell

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop which I purchased a few weeks ago. I am dual booting with Win 10 and Ubuntu Studio.
Recently, I installed the Synaptics DisplayLink driver in Studio so I could use a docking station with a second monitor. However, whether a second monitor is connected or not, only 1 window will display at a time. For example if I have a browser open and then fire up a terminal session, the browser disappears. If I click the browser in the panel the terminal session disappears. I installed Lazarus with the FPC but it is unusable as you can only see one thing at a time, object inspector, or form, or code, or toolbar.
I suspect it could be the Displaylink driver but don't know for sure as I only installed Studio a couple of days ago.
Is there a way to "reset" Studio or do I need to remove the Displaylink driver?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, first of all, Dell docking system is independent. You don't need a DisplayLink package to use secondary display, It should be sharing displays within another method. You can simply open `System Settings>Displays` to configure them.

Comment: Thanks Sadaharu. Yes, I know I don't need the DisplayLink package to use a second monitor but I do need it if I want to use the docking station (which works on Win 10). I got the docking station so I only have to plug in one cable instead of two monitor cables a keyboard and a mouse. I have deleted the package and it has made no difference. If I use OpenBox or LXDE I can display any number of windows but xubuntu adn xfce will not display more than one window at a time.